# Need help to print

Tags: unix, awk

i have a .txt file with following rows

```
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE30401 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE30397 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE30402 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE30398 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE30399 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE30396 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE30400 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE30403 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE30395 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- BCDEH9009001 Adapter- 
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE31761 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE31853 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- ABCDE31852 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- JKLMN41818 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- JKLMN41817 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- JKLMN41818 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- JKLMN41817 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- JKLMN41817                            
Error code:JOB ID- JKLMN41818                            
Error code:JOB ID- BCDHJ21885001 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- BCDHJ21885001 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- BCDHJ21885001 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- BCDHJ21885001 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- RTUEJ9006001 Adapter-
Error code:JOB ID- RTUEJ9007001Adapter-  
Error code:JOB ID- RTUEJ9008001Adapter-  
Error code:JOB ID- RTUEJ9010001Adapter-  
Error code:JOB ID- RTUEJ9011001Adapter-  
Error code:JOB ID- RTUEJ9012001Adapter-  
Error code:JOB ID- RTUEJ9013001Adapter-  
Error code:JOB ID- RTUEJ9080001Adapter-  
Error code:JOB ID- RTUEJ9015001Adapter-
```

i want to print all the values between JOB ID- & Adapter-

Comment: 3 points here, 1st- Always wrap your code in CODE TAGS. 2nd- Always show samples of input and output. 3rd- Please do add your efforts in your post which you have done, let us know once done.

Comment: `TUEJ9007001Adapter` is this correct, or is there supposed to be a space?

Comment: yes..it is correct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words?](/questions/13242469/how-to-use-sed-grep-to-extract-text-between-two-words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{gsub(/.*JOB ID- |Adapter.*| +$/,"")} 1'  Input_file
```

Comment: it works properly.. thanks for prompt help...